# How come the p-norm only works for $p \geq 1$?

Tags: general-topology

The p-norm metric.  If the p-norm metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ works for the value $p = \frac{3}{2}$, why not for $p = \frac{1}{2}$?  It seems to me that it should fail for both for the same reasons (we can get an imaginary measurement, and all metrics are supposed to yield real measurements), but according to my book it is not defined exclusively for $0 < p < 1$.

Comment: Neither has "imaginary measurements" as we take roots of absolute values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define $$\|x\|_p = \left( |x_1|^p + \cdots + |x_n|^p \right)^{1/p}$$ then for $0 < p < 1$ it isn't a norm. For instance, if $x = (1,0,\ldots,0)$ and $y = (0,1,0,\ldots,0)$ then $\|x\|_p = 1$, $\|y\|_p = 1$, yet $\|x+y\|_p = 2^{1/p}$ so that $$\|x\|_p + \|y\|_p < \|x+y\|_p$$ if $0 < p < 1$.

You can (sort of) circumvent this problem if you use $$|||x|||_p = |x_1|^p + \cdots + |x_n|^p.$$
In this case the triangle inequality holds but in general $|||\alpha x|||_p \not= |\alpha| \, |||x|||_p$ so it still isn't a norm. Bummer.

Comment: perfect explanation, thank you

Comment: You're welcome.